# Double-click installer in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, debian

I'm trying to update our installer so a user can simply double-click on a file and have all the dependencies and our software installed easily. This is a suite of applications that will are deployed on a clean [Ubuntu 8.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_8.04_LTS_(Hardy_Heron)) (Hardy Heron) installation. I have investigated making a *.deb* file, but listing the dependencies doesn't work, because there isn't any Internet access available. And, any script that would set up a local [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) repository would still need to be run from the command line. Is there a way to put a *.deb* file inside of a *.deb* file?

I know many companies ship shell scripts that you have to *chmod +x*, and then execute. This is not acceptable. It is ridiculous that this isn't possible; especially considering the distribution and architecture is fixed.

Comment: So you are saying you already know it is impossible?

Comment: I know it is impossible given the limited information I have. Other companies (such as Adobe) must support multiple distros, so they use executable bash scripts. Though they work across distros, the usability is horrible.

Comment: Requiring chmod +x is considered a security feature. There are GUI frontends for this if need be...

Comment: Users shouldn't have to know or care about the executable status of a particular file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [makeself](http://megastep.org/makeself/) self-extracting executable that starts the install script using sudo will work.

The user can either run it from a terminal (after chmod-ing it) or can double-click it and tell it to "Run" from the prompt.

Answer (score 4):

If you are totally confident that it will be installed on the same system every time, you can find the list of package dependencies yourself, fetch them from the Ubuntu repositories, and package them up with your software. You just have to be clear that your software is for a specific version, probably deal with things like keeping up with maintenance releases.

You can also easily install with a script. As for your complaint about making scripts executable, well, I don't know how you're shipping your product, but since you say it's going somewhere without Internet access, I assume it's going to be copied from some kind of media. If you make the script executable when you put it on that media, you're done.

If you'd like to do this using packages, you can create a [CD-ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CD-ROM) which contains a package repository. You can find all kinds of information on this with Google Search. For starters, try this - it's a GUI for doing it. http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/

Comment: The app is distributed as a tar file, I believe. But users still have to extract it themselves and run the script.

Comment: Well, you could certainly use that tar file as the data for a .deb package, and use the script to create the rest of the package.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to put deb-files into deb-files. The only thing you need to do is to configure the appropriate scripts.

A .deb-file consists of:

- 1x control.tar.gz: contains a file "control" (describes the package) and optional files like "postinst" (script executed right after extraction). There are other files you might include, and Google Search should deliver information about the available scripts.
- 1x data.tar.gz: contains some structure of root-filesystem which contains files/folders that need to be (re-)placed. Additionally, you may configure the behaviour in the mentioned scripts.
- 1x debian-binary: as far as I remember, this is simply a version number in a file. I don't know exactly what it means; just remember that in most of the cases this is 2.0.

So you now may put your .deb files in the data-package. Those are extracted by your script... and installed using:

```
# dpkg -i yourpackage1.deb yourpackage2.deb
```

Comment: The post-install script can't safely recursively invoke dpkg, so this won't work.

Comment: does it need to do it recursively? what if he's for example having all the .deb files in the /tmp-folder of the data-archive. the shell-script den dpkg-i's all of those files in one step... what's wrong with that?